# Why am I getting a segfault in this genetic algorithm problem?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to solve a CodeWars problem called "Training on Binary Genetic Algorithms." There is a fitness function that is preloaded. When the program is run, a test function creates a random 35-bit string and it uses my run function which is supposed to return the same 35-bit string. This string is supposed to be found using a genetic algorithm.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef double fitness_t (const char *, ...);
extern fitness_t fitness;

void generate (size_t length, char * s)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    s[i] = rand() % 2 + 48;
}

double sum(size_t n, double ar[n])
{
  double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sum += ar[i];
  return sum;
}
  
void select (int size, char* population[size], double fitnesses[size])
{
  double probabilities[size]; // normalized to 1
  double r;                   // random number
  int s1, s2;
  int i;
  
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    probabilities[i] = fitnesses[i] / sum(size, fitnesses);
  
  // select first chromosome
  r = (double)(rand() % 1000000) / 1000000; // generates a random float between 0 and 1
  for (i = 0; i < size && r > 0; i++)
    r -= probabilities[i];
  s1 = i;
  
  // select second chromosome
  s2 = s1;
  while (s2 == s1) // ensures the two chromosomes aren't the same
  {
    r = (double)(rand() % 1000000) / 1000000; // generates a random float between 0 and 1
    for (i = 0; i < size && r > 0; i++)
      r -= probabilities[i];
    s2 = i;
  }

  // places these two chromosomes on top
  char * temp = population[0];
  population[0] = population[s1];
  population[s1] = temp;
  
  temp = population[1];
  population[1] = population[s2];
  population[s2] = temp;
}

void crossover (size_t n, char* s1, char* s2)
{
  int r = rand() % n; // select a random bit to cross over at
  char temp;

  for (size_t i = r; i < n; i++) // swap every bit from bit r to bit n
  {
    temp = s1[i];
    s1[i] = s2[i];
    s2[i] = temp;
  }
}
 
void mutate (size_t n, char* s, double p)
{
  double r;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) // for each bit
  {
    r = (double)(rand() % 1000000) / 1000000;  // random float between 0 and 1
    if (r <= p)       // if random number is less than probability
    {
      if (s[i] == '1') s[i] = '0';    // swap 0s and 1s
      else s[i] = '1';
    }
  }
}

void bubbleSortPop(int size, char * population[size], double fitnesses[size])
{
    int i, j;
    char * temp_chrome;
    double temp_fitness;
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        // Last i elements are already in place
        for (j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++)
            if (fitnesses[j] < fitnesses[j + 1])
            {
              temp_chrome = population[j];
              population[j] = population[j+1];
              population[j+1] = temp_chrome;
              
              temp_fitness = fitnesses[j];
              fitnesses[j] = fitnesses[j+1];
              fitnesses[j+1] = temp_fitness;
            }
}

// this function changes the population.
// select, crossover, mutate
void evolve(fitness_t f, size_t size, int length, char * population[size], 
            double fitnesses[size], double p_c, double p_m)
{
  char * s1, * s2;
  double f1, f2;
  char * temp_pop[size+2];
  double temp_fit[size+2];
  int i;
  double r;
  
  // moves two selected parents to the top
  select(size, population, fitnesses); 
  
  // begin reproduction process; duplicate the chromosomes
  s1 = population[0];
  s2 = population[1];
 
  // crossover
  r = (double)(rand() % 1000000) / 1000000;  // random float between 0 and 1
  if (r < p_c)                              // probability of crossing over
    crossover(length, s1, s2);              // commences with crossover
  
  // mutate
  mutate(length, s1, p_m);
  mutate(length, s2, p_m);
  
  // calculate fitnesses
  f1 = f(s1);
  f2 = f(s2);
  
  // merge fitneses
  // copy original fitnesses into temp_fit
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    temp_fit[i] = fitnesses[i];
  // add new fitnesses
  temp_fit[size] = f1;
  temp_fit[size+1] = f2;  
  
  // merge children into population
  // copy original population into temp_pop
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    temp_pop[i] = population[i];
  // add two children to temp_pop
  temp_pop[size] = s1;
  temp_pop[size+1] = s2;
 
  // sort fitnesses and population
  bubbleSortPop(size+2, temp_pop, temp_fit);
  
  // add first 100 elements of temp_pop and fit to population and fitnesses
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    population[i] = temp_pop[i];
    fitnesses[i] = temp_fit[i];
  }

}

char* runN (fitness_t f, int length, double p_c, double p_m, size_t iterations) {
}

char* run (fitness_t f, int length, double p_c, double p_m)
{
  size_t size = 100;
  char * population[size];
  double fitnesses[size];
  size_t i;
  int r;
  
  srand(time(0));
  
  // initialize population array
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    population[i] = malloc((length+1) * sizeof(char));

  // generate original population
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
  {
    generate(length, population[i]);  
    fitnesses[i] = f(population[i]);
    printf("[%2d] %s %lf\n", i, population[i], fitnesses[i]);
  }
 
  // evolve the population
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    evolve(f, size, length, population, fitnesses, p_c, p_m);
  
//   print result
  printf("\nAFTER EVOLUTION\n");
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) // generates original population
    printf("[%2d] %s %lf\n", i, population[i], fitnesses[i]);
  
  // store best chromosome and free memory
  char ret[length+1];
  strcpy(ret, population[0]);
  
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    free(population[i]);
  
  return ret;
}
```

The issue is when I run my code, it nearly always comes out with a segfault at some point while printing the contents of population and fitness.

Comment: Compiling your code (with standard settings) generates a lot of warnings. You should fix those. A possible cause is that you return a local (stack allocated) array in your `run()` function. This ceases to exist when the function exits, and will generate some undefined behaviour.

Comment: Minor: Use `s[i] = rand() % 2 + '0';`, not `s[i] = rand() % 2 + 48;` to make the code clearer and portable.

Comment: By mutating the top 2 most fit strings without first giving each a chance to reproduce, this logic will not "improve" the population. Perhaps sort by fitness first, then replace the 2 worst performers with copies of the 2 best and then mutate one of each of those. As is, evolve() makes the population as likely to go backwards as forwards...

Comment: In `run()`, the "best" string is copied into a local array `ret` whose address is returned from the function. That array goes out of scope when the function ends. Subsequent access is UB. (Since each individual is allocated their own string, you could free those who didn't qualify and return the heap buffer of the leader for the caller to use and free later.)

Comment: With time to kill until NYE, may as well waste it on this question... When you evolve, only 2 players (of 100) are involved... The rest just hang around unchanged (unmutated or mated) until 1 of the 2 evolves in the wrong direction... you might want to "liven things up" by given everyone a chance to evolve on each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

At least these problems:

**Attempting to print a non-string with `"%s"`**

Code uses `"%s"` and passes `population[i]` as if it points to a *string*.  `population[i]` does not point to a *string* as it does not certainly have a *null character*.  Result *undefined behavior* (UB).  Perhaps attempting to access beyond allocated memory.

```
// Undefined behavior: population[i] not a string
printf("[%2d] %s %lf\n", i, population[i], fitnesses[i]);
```

Set the null character.

```
generate(length, population[i]);
population[i][length] = '\0'; // Add this here or equivalent in `generate()`.
```

**Many compiler warnings (20+)**

Enable all compiler warnings and fix those.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It was all the places where I tried to copy a string by making a string pointer and assigning it the same address as the pointer I wanted to copy. For example, in 'select', when I tried to move the two strings to the top, I did

```
char * temp = population[0];
population[0] = population[s1];
population[s1] = temp;
  
temp = population[1];
population[1] = population[s2];
population[s2] = temp;
```

I changed this to using strcpy(). I made the same mistake in 'evolve' where I tried to duplicate the chromosomes by just copying their address into variables, rather than the strings themselves:

```
char * s1, * s2;
// begin reproduction process; duplicate the chromosomes
s1 = population[0];
s2 = population[1];
```

I changed it to this:

```
char s1[length+1], s2[length+1];
strcpy(s1, population[0]);
strcpy(s2, population[1]);
```

After I made this change the segfault went away. Thanks for all your answers.